# WSO2 Header Mediation, 401

Tags: header, http-headers, wso2, wso2-esb

I would like to return a 401 response on a message after a failed authentication.  I believe this can be done through a header mediation, but not sure.  I just dont know what namespace it would be or what to set it to.

I believe #status#, and HTTP/1.1 401, respectively.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP_SC 
http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/properties_guide.html

Comment: `<header name="To" action="remove"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="401" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>`